# Passing values to method parameters to create a CGRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm very new to Objective-C. I'm trying to write a method where I create a UIImageView that contains an image file at a specific size.

Here's my method:

```
- (void)setImageViewElements:(UIImageView *)imageViewName : (NSString *)imageName : (NSInteger )topX : (NSInteger )topY : (NSInteger )imageWidth : (NSInteger )imageHeight
{
    imageViewName = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(topX, topY, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
    [imageViewName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Xcode throws this warning for the method:
Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'setImageViewElements::::::': 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') vs 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

I'd like to call it like this:

```
[self setImageViewElements:myImageView :@"myImage.png" :150 :532 :112 :82];
```

Xcode throws this warning for the call:
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *');

I've tried changing the parameters to float, CGFloat and int, but I get the same variation of error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Maury

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Conflicting parameter types in implementation..." suggests the method signature in your .h file doesn't match what you have in the .m file. Maybe your .h still has an older version that uses `CGFloat`?

As a side suggestion, why not pass in "larger" objects and structs rather than separate image names, x, y, width, and height arguments? Something like:

```
- (void) setImageViewElements:(UIImageView *)imageViewName
                    withImage:(UIImage *)image
                      inFrame:(CGRect)rect
```

You would then call it like this:

```
[self setImageViewElements:myImageView
                 withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
                   inFrame:CGRectMake(150, 532, 112, 82)];
```

Using named parameters is generally thought of as good style too.

Answer (score 0):

Your header file has a declaration for this method that has at least one `CGFloat *` where in the definition you have `NSInteger`.

The compiler's complaining in the first warning about that conflict. The second warning comes because the compiler is using the version in the header to generate code, and it thinks you want it to use an integer as a pointer to a `CGFloat`, which isn't a good idea.

There are two problems here. First, parameters that are `CGFloat`s don't need to be pointers. Those are primitive types, not objects. Second, the conflict between the declaration and definition. Third, your method name lacks labels for the parameters, which is legal but completely contrary to established style, and just plain hard to read. Three problems.

Declaration:

```
- (void)prepareImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView withImageName:(NSString *)name originX:(CGFloat)topX originY:(CGFloat)topY width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height;
```

Make sure the definition looks the same, especially including the types of the parameters.

You could also make this easier to read by just making the method take a `CGRect` parameter:

```
- (void)prepareImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView withImageName:(NSString *)name frame:(CGRect)frame;
```

Which you then call like this:

```
[self prepareImageView:myImageView withImageName:@"myImage.png" frame:(CGRect){150, 532, 112, 82}];
```